# Obj-C: call super class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, super

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    <CODE BEFORE>
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    <CODE AFTER>
}
```

What is correct, to put all code before or after the super call ?
Its working both ways, but I don't know if its better to wait for the call until the end or submit it at the beginning ?

cheers endo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, your code should go **after** the call to super. The one obvious exception is dealloc, in which case you want to call `[super dealloc]` after you've cleaned up after yourself.

Answer (score 9):

The general rule of thumb is to call it first when setting things up (like here) and call it last when tearing things down.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific case, really:

- For initialization / cleanup, obviously, since the subclass depends on its superclass state, it should initialize after and cleanup before.
- In general, you might very well need to add behavior both before and after the super-call, or even omit the super-call entirely (that's what method override is for, after all).

In this precise case, see the other answers; but since `viewDidAppear:` is a notification-like method, it really depends whether your code needs a fully initialized object, or takes part in the initialization itself and so must only proceed with the super-call once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're doing.  Can you provide some context around the objects you're using?

For example, in the context of *object destruction* , you call super last.

```
- (void)dealloc {
[someObj release];

[super dealloc];
```

}